# How to access value of an ASP textbox that contains variable in its ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am creating a total of `n` textbox whenever i enter the value `n` on a textbox and click on a button in ASP.NET. Im using the below code for that,

```
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(text_flats_blocks.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        TextBox MyTextBox = new TextBox();
        MyTextBox.ID = "text_" + (i+1);
        panel_flats_blocks.Controls.Add(MyTextBox);
        MyTextBox.CssClass = "textblock";
        Literal lit = new Literal();
        lit.Text = "<br /><br />";
        panel_flats_blocks.Controls.Add(lit);
    }
```

This works fine and the textboxes are created. Then i enter some values to the textboxes and click on another button. On clicking the second button the values entered in the textboxes should be obtained using C#. But i have created ID for these textboxes using variables like this `text_ + (i+1)` that creates the names as `text_1`, `text_2` etc. How can i use this as an ID to access the textbox value like `id.Text` but here the id contains variable. I want to use loop to iterate for `n` times and access all values from all `n` textboxes and store them in a list. How can i do this using C#?

Comment: Do you want to access them with Javascript or on the server? It's not clear.

Comment: i want to access them in server side using C#

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**FindControl**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

```
public void SecondButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(text_flats_blocks.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var control= (TextBox)FindControl("text_" + (i+1));
        //now you have the controls and you can do whatever you want with them 
    }
}
```